# CSS Grid splitting homepage into two parts

Tags: css, css-grid, particles.js

having some trouble with CSS grid layout. I used grid on my class Introduction and it has split my particles and introduction paragraph into two sections.

What I want is for the particles to cover the whole 100vh of the background

Heres a fiddle:

```
Notice in the fiddle, my particles arent in the background
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shv0ytgo/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move your paragraph tag outside of particles.
So your html will be like

```
  <div class="headerdata">      
        <p id="Introduction" class="css-typing">
            Hi, I'm <strong>Billy Bob</strong>.
        <br/><br/>
            I'm a <strong>front-end</strong> and <strong>back-end</strong> developer.
        </p>
  </div>
    <header id="particles-js">
    </header>
```

and your CSS will be like

```
.headerdata {
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#030711e8;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 60px;
    width:100%;
}
header{
  position:absolute; width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;  
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: 50% 50%; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/gLq56ptv/

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar problem with particles. If you want particles to be your whole background, here's my solution:

- you shouldn't wrap all your content in particles div, particles div should be closed
- after particles should go a div that wraps all your content, it should have a relative position and a z-index bigger than particles'. Prticles' position should be fixed. Basically, your html structure shoould look like this:

```css
.overlay {
   z-index: 100;
   position: relative;
}
#particles-js {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 0;
    display:grid;
    height:100vh;
    background-color:#030711e8;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <div class="overlay">
        <p>  your introduction  </p>
        <main>  your content  </main>
    </div>  
</body>
```